# Rails, Bootstrap modal, jQuery- tie event to invalid form re-display

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've been searching for a solution for a while, but I'm coming up empty.

I've got some jQuery logic tied to `.on('shown'...)` for my Bootstrap modal.  It's responsible for modifying select options and disabling fields, along with a few other things.  Everything is working except when the modal form is submitted and fails validation (the validation is in the form object, no client-side validation).  The modal re-displays with the correct errors, but I need to execute the same jQuery that's tied to `'shown'`.

Currently, when the modal is re-displayed, the selects contain the unmodified options, for example, the `<%= f.input :city_id, collection: City.active ... %>` select will show all cities within the `:active` scope, but on `'shown'`, I send a `$.getJSON` request to further refine the list of cities in the select, and I need to be able to do that when the invalid form is re-displayed.

I'm not sure what other code might be useful to include in my question, so please let me know if I should add other bits.  I'm using `simple_form` if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not added your code which could have been great support in answering this question.
 Still from you explanation, what i seems is, after validation if it fails still you want to execute some javascript logic (to show/ hide or do whatever you want).. then i think you do something like this :

lets say this is the action where you validation fails.

```
def create
@result = @record.valid?
#will be false if validation failed.
end
```

then create another create.js.erb file for that particular aciton..

```
#create.js.erb
<% unless @result %> 
//write your js code here, whatever you wish to do after validation failure. 
<% end %>
```